# test when directories are in sync using rsync

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

Is there any way to know from a bash script when a rsync command does not download anything (aka the folder is in sync)?, I've tried using the exit code, but is only different when an error happens.

Example of rsync downloading only the files not in sync:

$ rsync -av --progress humbo@hkremote:/home/humbo/dumps/*.gz .

```
receiving file list ...
9 files to consider
_dump_7.gz
    35927279 100%    1.19MB/s    0:00:28 (xfer#1, to-check=1/9)
_dump_8.gz
    39387704 100%    1.17MB/s    0:00:32 (xfer#2, to-check=0/9)

sent 64 bytes  received 75324472 bytes  1205192.58 bytes/sec
total size is 354448073  speedup is 4.71
```

$ echo $?

```
0
```

Files in sync:

$ rsync -av --progress humbo@hkremote:/home/humbo/dumps/*.gz .

```
receiving file list ...
9 files to consider

sent 20 bytes  received 205 bytes  90.00 bytes/sec
total size is 354448073  speedup is 1575324.77
```

$ echo $?

```
0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rsync --stats` then use `grep "Number of files transferred"` and then print this stat with `awk`, in this way:

```
rsync -av --stats --progress humbo@hkremote:/home/humbo/dumps/*.gz . | grep 'Number of files transferred' | awk -F ": " '{print $2}'
```

This result is 0 when nothing is transfered.

Answer (score 1):

Rsync does not have exit code that is different for when it runs a copy versus it copies nothing. The exit codes are only for failures resulting in issues with copies. You would have to write some logic around the the function in the bash script to tell if it did not copy any files.

http://wpkg.org/Rsync_exit_codes

Answer (score 1):

Never done this before, but it might work if your directories are not too big.

Create a`md5sum` before you start your `rsync` and compare with the `md5sum` after you finished. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
md5sum=$(ssh humbo@hkremote tar -c /home/humbo/dumps|md5sum)
.
.
# The rest of your script goes here
.
.
md5sum_after_rsync=$(ssh humbo@hkremote tar -c /home/humbo/dumps|md5sum)
if test $md5sum == $md5sum_after_rsync
then
    echo "nothing has changed"
else
    echo "something has changed"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rsync -i`. Empty output means no changes.

Or `rsync --stats` and parse the output ...

Comment: parse the result from --stats is the way to go IMHO

Answer (score 0):

run `rsync -n`, you'll get list of files that are out of sync:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ rsync --help | grep dry-run
 -n, --dry-run               perform a trial run with no changes made
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$
```